# Custom View is Causing Strange behavior with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am trying to use Romain Guy's [SpotlightView](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/13/android-recipe-2-fun-with-shaders/) to highlight a particular part of my Action Bar, but I'm running into some problems.  To start with, I've created a custom Action Bar which centers text via this layout, which works in a vacuum.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rel_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="-1"
        android:shadowRadius="1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, that's all well and good, and the title is centered as you can see here.

[image]

However, when I do the following everything gets messed up.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    SpotlightView spotlightView = new SpotlightView(this, null);

    // some slight changes I made to allow me to set information dynamically
    spotlightView.setTargetId(mActionbarTitle.getId());
    spotlightView.setMaskId(R.drawable.spot_mask);
    spotlightView.setAlpha(0.33f);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.rel_test);
    layout.add(spotlightView);
}
```

When the following happens.  Note that nothing is shown because I have stripped SpotlightView down basically to a call to super in the constructor, and a call to `super.onDraw()`.  I have also included the screenshot with the layout bounds shown here.

[image: Incorrect ActionBar]

As you can see, it looks like what happens is the wrapping `RelativeLayout` only spans the space between the back button and the action buttons, resulting in the `TextView` being only centered in that space.  However, why does that happen?  Is there any way around it?  Do I need to override `onMeasure` or another one of the `View` callbacks?

Also, interestingly, when I add another `TextView` to `rel_test` the title is still properly centered.

EDIT: Alright, so I narrowed it down to a problem caused by calling `setMaskId`, which in turn calls this block of code:

```
Bitmap a = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
Canvas c = new Canvas(a);
c.drawBitmap(b, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
```

When I comment out the line that is `c.drawBitmap(b, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);` everything works smoothly.  However, given that the code relies on having that canvas, I'm not quite sure what to do about removing it.

I'm not familiar with graphics on Android, so any advice on how to adapt the original code to create the same spotlight effect while not removing the centered Action Bar would be much appreciated.